# How to measure scoliosis angle?

Tags: spine, measurement, scoliosis

I am interested in how to measure scoliosis curve angle without X-Ray. As far as I know there are two ways to measure the angle - VCM and Cobb's angles. But again they require X-Ray. Can I measure the angle from photo like this?[image]

P.S.
I know scoliosis is not a disease, but there are no tags for this topic yet.